# getting outside of a loop in laravel 5 blade?

Tags: php, loops, laravel, laravel-blade

This seems simple yet I'm struggling with this. I'd like to get all these data {TotalRaces} separated by a comma for a Sparkline graph, however the leading or trailing comma will either cause a value of 0 at the beginning or the end of the sparkline (for an [example](http://cxr.datafun.me/racer/5572)). Any thoughts of how to remove the first, or last, comma? I need them in between the variables but not a the beginning or end.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!!

```
 @forelse ($pts as $p)
    ,{{ $p->TotalRaces }}   //causes zero at beginning of sparkline
 @empty

 @endforelse
```

OR

```
 @forelse ($pts as $p)
    {{ $p->TotalRaces }},   //causes zero at end of sparkline
 @empty

 @endforelse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little bit ugly code, but still:

```
 @forelse ($pts as $p)
 {{ $p->TotalRaces }} @if($p != end($pts)),   @endif
 @empty
```

Comment: @C.ToddLombardo If it solved your problem, you can mark the question as an answer, so that other users would know that it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi - Yes, I'm looking at where/how to do that and it is not very obvious.

[edit] - checked. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $pts is a collection

```
{{ implode(',', array_map(function($a){return $a['TotalRaces'];}, $pts->toArray())) }}
```

You want all the `TotalRaces` in an array, in order to implode them with a comma. So you transform your `$pts` collection into an array, and pass it to `array_map` to extract the `TotalRaces` property.

Comment: @C.ToddLombardo You should accept the answer to close the question, maybe? Or you ended up using another solution?

Comment: OK - Yes, apologies for my newbie-ness. It wasn't clear that a click of the checkmark was what's needed. Appreciate your help!!